# JavaScript exibir data do dia anterior ao atual

Tags: javascript

Tenho seguinte script que funciona certinho, porém na virada do mês ele não "monta" corretamente a data, por exemplo hoje, ele está mostrando a data 20181000

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate()-1;

var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) 
{
    dd='0'+dd;
} 

if(mm<10) 
{
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
var data_ok = today = yyyy+''+mm+''+dd;


var filename = 'ldrel_'+data_ok+'.txt'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var hoje = new Date();

var ontem = new Date(hoje.getTime());
ontem.setDate(hoje.getDate() - 1);

var dd = ontem.getDate();
var mm = ontem.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = ontem.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) 
{
dd='0'+dd;
}

if(mm<10) 
{
mm='0'+mm;
} 

var data_ok = yyyy+''+mm+''+dd;

var filename = 'LDREL_'+data_ok+'.txt'

console.log(filename);
```

A tarefa da instrução `new Date()` é criar um local na memória para todos os dados que uma data precisa armazenar. O que falta dessa tarefa são os dados - que data e hora são colocadas nesse ponto da memória. É aí que entram os parâmetros.

Se deixar os parâmetros vazios, o JavaScript considera que você deseja a data e hora atuais para esse novo objeto date.

Para criar um objeto date para uma data e hora especifica, você tem cinco maneiras de enviar valores como um parâmetro à função construtora new Date():

1. new Date("mês dd, aaaa hh:mm:ss")
2. new Date("mês dd, aaaaa")
3. new Date("aa,mês,dd,hh,mm,ss")
4. new Date("aa,mês,dd")
5. new Date(milissegundos)

A maior parte dos métodos de um objeto date serve para leitura de partes da informaç]ão de data e hora e para a mudança da data e hora armazenadas no objeto. Essas duas categorias de métodos são facilmente identificáveis, pois começam com a palavra-chave `get` ou `set`

`objDate.getTime()` - milissegundos desde 1/1/70 00:00:00 GMT

`objDate.setDate(val)` - dia dentro do mês (1-31)

`objDate.getDate()` - data dentro do mês

[**Date**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Legal, realmente seu script está capturando a data correta, como eu faço para o resultado final apareça somente LDREL_20180930.txt  ?

Comment: @EdvaldoLucena Do mesmo jeito que vc fez no seu script, veja resposta editada. Não esqueça de marcar como aceita se resolveu seu problema!

Answer (score 2):

Tem uma forma bem mais simples de se fazer isso usando o `setTime()`.
Esse comando arruma as horas do objeto data a sua escolha, aceitando parametros de -1 a 24. De 0 a 23, ele arrumaas horas corretamente, entretanto, com o 24 ele passa para o dia seguinte, e com o -1 para a ultima hora do dia anterior. Ou seja.

```
var hoje = new Date();
var ontem = new Date().setHours(-1);
ontem = new Date(ontem) // o comando setHours devolve a data em milisegundos

var dataformatada = ontem.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'); // '30/09/2018'
dataformatada = dataformatada.split('/').reverse().join('') // '20180930'
var filename = 'LDREL_'+dataformatada+'.txt'

console.log(filename); // LDREL_20180930.txt
```

Comment: O retorno de `toLocaleDateString` varia conforme o locale do browser, seria melhor especificar o locale para garantir que sempre usará o formato brasileiro: `toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')`. O meu browser, por exemplo, está setado com `en-US` (sei lá pq está em inglês, nem lembrava disso) e `toLocaleDateString()` retorna no formato M/D/YYYY (9/30/2018)

Comment: Obrigado pelo apontamento, vou ajustar.